# Strange questions about comparing the Integer result of Spring DAO

Tags: java, spring, integer, equals, dao

I've got a strange question here.

Sup entity:

```
public class Sup implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5898846627874143178L;
    private Integer state;

    public Integer getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(Integer state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Code1:

```
 @Override
public void test() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //Just a simple query sql,the result is always the same
            //and the state of 'sup' is always 0;
            Sup sup = supDao.querySupByid(40017);
            Integer state = sup.getState();
            System.out.println("my state:" + state);
            if (state!=Integer.valueOf(0)) {
                System.out.println("     ["+ i + "]>>>>0!=0");
            }
        }
}
```

the querySupByid method:

```
@Select("SELECT state FROM TBL_SUP WHERE ID=#{supId} ")
Sup querySupByid(@Param("supId")Integer sup);
```

part of result like this:

- my state:0
- my state:0
- [1]>>>>0!=0
- my state:0
- [2]>>>>0!=0
- my state:0
- [3]>>>>0!=0

....

The result I expected is 10 of "my state:0".
As you can see,most results expect the first loop are all wrong(`state!=Integer.valueOf(0)` cause the state is always 0 so here should always be false), next I changed some code like this

Code2:

```
@Override
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Sup sup = supDao.querySupByid(40017);
            Integer state = sup.getState();
            System.out.println("my state:" + state);
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            if (state!=Integer.valueOf(0)) {
                System.out.println("     ["+ i + "]>>>>0!=0");
            }
        }
}
```

in every loop I pause 5 seconds  and the result became this:

- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0
- my state:0

clearly I've got the correct result finally;
next I change the code again;

Code3:

```
@Override
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Sup sup = new Sup();//supDao.querySupByid(40017);
            sup.setState(0);
            Integer state = sup.getState();
            System.out.println("my state:" + state);
            if (state!=Integer.valueOf(0)) {
                System.out.println("     ["+ i + "]>>>>0!=0");
            }
        }
}
```

In Code3 the result is also correct,and I changed the code once again:

Code4:

```
@Override
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Sup sup =supDao.querySupByid(40017);
            Integer state = sup.getState();
            System.out.println("my state:" + state);
            if (!state.equals(Integer.valueOf(0))) {
                System.out.println("     ["+ i + "]>>>>0!=0");
            }
        }
}
```

the same result with Code3 ,but I can't figure out the reasonable explanation.

I've figured out ,the result is caused by cache;first result has been serialized to cache,the following result getting from cache has been deserialized.So the later result is not "=="the former result, what a stupid mistake

Comment: "As you can see ,most of results are wrong" - No I dont see why  that result is wrong and you didnt explained what would be "good" result. You are fetching 10 times the same entity and the state is the same for all of them, 0 in your case. I dont see whi would it differ over iterations.

Comment: When comparing boxed primitives, always use `equals`, not `==` or `!=`. The latter test for object identity.

Comment: The explanation lies in the implementation of `sup.getState()` and `supDao.querySupByid(40017)`. We need to see this.

Answer (score 0):

Do not compare `Integer` objects with `==`  and `!=`. Those operators will check if two objects are the same, not if they have the same value, and there is no guarantee that the same `Integer` object is always returned by `valueOf` for a given value. Always use `equals` for the `Integer` object.

Answer (score 0):

For comparision use `Integer.compare(int,int)`. Result of `0` will mean equality.